# SonarLint throws IllegalStateException -> Failed to read local issue store index

Tags: java, eclipse, analysis, illegalstateexception, sonarlint

I'm currently working in my Job with Eclipse and Java. We should use SonarLint to get some cleaner code and 'till yesterday everything was fine. 
But yesterday morning, when I opened Eclipse, SonarLint throw me the following errormessage.

I've already searched in Google, deleted the .sonarlint folder, also the settingsfolder of eclipse and the .sonarlint folder inside the eclipse-workspace. Everyone of them where recreated by restarting eclipse but nothing helped here. I'm still getting the error:

```
Starting SonarLint for Eclipse 4.2.0.201909192007
SonarLint processing file /rap-server-core/src/main/java/com/rapidclipse/framework/server/ui/filter/FilterComponent.java...
Starting standalone SonarLint engine 4.2.0.201909192007...
Found 17 issue(s)
Error during execution of SonarLint analysis
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read local issue store index
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.StringStoreIndex.load(StringStoreIndex.java:55)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.StringStoreIndex.keys(StringStoreIndex.java:45)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.IndexedObjectStore.deleteInvalid(IndexedObjectStore.java:78)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.IssueStore.<init>(IssueStore.java:62)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.SonarLintCorePlugin.lambda$0(SonarLintCorePlugin.java:102)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.IssueTrackerRegistry.newTracker(IssueTrackerRegistry.java:54)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.IssueTrackerRegistry.getOrCreate(IssueTrackerRegistry.java:43)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.SonarLintCorePlugin.getOrCreateIssueTracker(SonarLintCorePlugin.java:146)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.trackIssues(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:317)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.lambda$15(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2317)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.updateMarkers(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:302)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.runAnalysisAndUpdateMarkers(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:209)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.doRun(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:169)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractSonarProjectJob.run(AbstractSonarProjectJob.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:102)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$StreamDecoder.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:2066)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.proto.Sonarlint$StorageIndex.<init>(Sonarlint.java:2496)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.proto.Sonarlint$StorageIndex.<init>(Sonarlint.java:2482)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.proto.Sonarlint$StorageIndex$1.parsePartialFrom(Sonarlint.java:3126)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.proto.Sonarlint$StorageIndex$1.parsePartialFrom(Sonarlint.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:215)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:232)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:237)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.parseWithIOException(GeneratedMessageV3.java:332)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.proto.Sonarlint$StorageIndex.parseFrom(Sonarlint.java:2746)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.StringStoreIndex.load(StringStoreIndex.java:53)
    ... 16 more
```

I don't know what the problem is and as I said google couldn't help me that much (maybe I'm just to stupid for google idk)

Comment: try to delete the directory /sonarlint/issuestore/.  In intellij it is at the location [project_directory]/.idea/sonarlint/issuestore/. Check the same for eclipse

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I can't find such a folder within my eclipse directory nor in any other sonarlint folder...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I had tried downgrading from 5.0 to 4.3, but that did not solve the issue.

So I did some investigation and found that in the source code `sonarlint-eclipse/org.sonarlint.eclipse.core/src/org/sonarlint/eclipse/core/internal/tracking/StringStoreIndex.java` line 53 ultimately lead to `public static final String INDEX_FILENAME = "index.pb";` (line 34).

So what I did was `del /s /q /f index.pb` within the Eclipse, Maven and Workspace folders. And it was under the Workspace `.metadata\.plugins` folder.

And now, the error seems to be gone. SonarLint is finally reporting on where the "smelly" code is again.

I have a feeling that the permissions for `index.pb` got messed-up or not updated, and could not load the file as the error message suggested.

But back to normal now. :)

Comment: Sadly it didn't work for me. 
I removed my existing Sonar binding, uninstalled sonar plugin and reinstalled the latest version, and tried your command. It did remove a couple of index.pb files in .plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\NameOfMyProjects but I still have an error.
Error during execution of SonarLint analysis
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read issues
 at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.IssueStore.lambda$0(IssueStore.java:51...

Comment: Fair. Although, "Failed to read issues at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.tracking.IssueStore.lambda$0(IssueStore.java:51" sounds a bit different. Did you remove the files while Eclipse was open or closed?

Comment: Eclipse was probably close. I had the same error message, this new one came after deleting index.pb files. Well it was worth a shot ;)

Comment: This question and answer is eclipse related but it helped me to workaround the problem in intellij: `$ find . -name "index.pb" -print` resulted in 
`./.idea/sonarlint/issuestore/index.pb` which I deleted and it started to work again

Comment: `del /s /q /f index.pb` in in eclipse workspace worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I've just reinstalled Eclipse... now everything works fine again.
I still don't know what problem caus' this error, but now that it's gone I just hope it'll never come back :D

For the reinstalling I've only deleted every folder, who has something to do with eclipse. Except, of course, my workspace folder^^

Answer (score 0):

Update the Sonarlint installed in the IDE.

Steps in Eclipse and STS IDE:

Select Help, then "Eclipse Marketplace", search for SonarLint, click on the Installed Icon, finally select "Update".